# Jquery ajax call and each loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

My each loop isn't working and it sends data without loop. Here is my code:

```
function copyText() {
$("#ppages").each(function() {
        var form_data = {
            idstrony: $(this).attr("class"),
            strona: $(this).val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "save.php",
            data: form_data
        });
    });
    };
```

What i'm doing wrong? I'll appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: `#ppages` refers to the id of one element. Maybe you should try to reference a class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize the form_data before posting, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/serialize/